# Making outline-regexp recognise heading titles

Tags: outline

I want to change the outline heading levels from being composed of a series of semicolons, to only three semicolons followed by `HN` or `MN`, where `N` is the corresponding level.

Hence

```
;;; H1 Title Level 1
;;; H2 Title Level 2
```

But currently the `outline-regexp` does not recognise any title text next to the heading.  What can I do for outline-regexp to recognise this ?

```
(defvar elisp-hglevels
  '( (";;; H1" . 1) (";;; H2" . 2) (";;; H3" . 3) (";;; H4" . 4)
     (";;; H5" . 5) (";;; H6" . 6) (";;; H7" . 7) (";;; H8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for standard (canonical) headings.")

(defun elisp-hgcogni ()
  "Set the cognitive understanding of elisp outlines."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (hrklevels elisp-hglevels) )

    (setq outline-regexp
           (concat (regexp-opt (mapcar 'car hrklevels)) "\\>"))
    (setq outline-heading-alist hrklevels)) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make a very specific and constraining change to a regular expression. Therefore, for further information on the topic, you will want to look at this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html

What you seem to want to do, however, is the following:

`(setq-local outline-regexp ";;; H[[:digit:]]")`

I believe you should set this after you toggle `outline-mode` in the desired buffer.

Comment: Do I need to specify that I allow a space followed by text after the digit ?

Comment: You are right regarding first enabling `outline-mode`.

Comment: @Pampalula Since you have accepted this as the answer, I assume the question you asked here is obsolete?